# Combobox looses text and displays it mirrored

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a winform with a dropdown combobox. This combobox contains all employees names and acts as an address book:
[image: combobox with users]

So far so Good. The only issue is that our active directory has some mixed up last/first names and I do not know the last name of every single person. The auto suggest of the combobox however always starts with the beginning of the string so I can only search by lastname.

For this reason I tried to implement something like a fuzzy search.

The search itself is working great:
[image]

But with the implementation of my search, I am getting a very weird behavior, but first my implementation, so you know what I am talking about.

**Form1.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TicketCreator
{
    public partial class TicketCreator_UI : Form
    {
        DataTable AllNames = new DataTable();
        List<(string name, string mail)> DomainSearchResult = new List<(string name, string mail)>();
        List<string> GeneratedNames = new List<string>();
        public TicketCreator_UI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillDropDown();
        }

        private void User_dropdown_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            //string text = user_dropdown.Text;
            string name = $"{user_dropdown.Text}{e.KeyChar.ToString()}";//join previous text and new pressed char
            DataRow[] rows = AllNames.Select($"UserName LIKE '%{name}%'");
            DataTable filteredTable = AllNames.Clone();
            foreach (DataRow r in rows)
                filteredTable.ImportRow(r);
            user_dropdown.DataSource = null;
            user_dropdown.DataSource = filteredTable.DefaultView;
            user_dropdown.DisplayMember = "UserName";
            user_dropdown.SelectedIndex = -1;
            //user_dropdown.Text = text;
        }
        private void FillDropDown()
        {
            // fill users combobox
            DomainSearchResult = ADTools.ListUsers();
            foreach ((string name, string mail) user in DomainSearchResult)
            {
                GeneratedNames.Add($"{user.name} <{user.mail}>");
            }
            AllNames.Columns.Add("UserName");
            foreach (string row in GeneratedNames)
                AllNames.Rows.Add(row);
            user_dropdown.DataSource = GeneratedNames;
            user_dropdown.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

First, `FillDropDown()` is called which will pull the users from AD and pushes them into the combobox for once.

Afterwards, when a key press is made, fuzzy search is executed and the ComboBox is updated.

Have a look at the screenshot:
[image]
The last letter I typed is shown but as soon as I type a new one, it is beeing replaced by the newest input. In this example I typed "Julian" so far.

I tried to counterfeit this behavior by first getting the text of the ComboBox, then updating the datasource and finally reinserting the text:

```
private void User_dropdown_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    string text = user_dropdown.Text; // Updated
    string name = $"{user_dropdown.Text}{e.KeyChar.ToString()}";//join previous text and new pressed char
    DataRow[] rows = AllNames.Select($"UserName LIKE '%{name}%'");
    DataTable filteredTable = AllNames.Clone();
    foreach (DataRow r in rows)
        filteredTable.ImportRow(r);
    user_dropdown.DataSource = null;
    user_dropdown.DataSource = filteredTable.DefaultView;
    user_dropdown.DisplayMember = "UserName";
    user_dropdown.SelectedIndex = -1;
    user_dropdown.Text = text; // Updated
}
```

The text now stays within the ComboBox but is mirrored. The following example shows up, when I type "Julian Bechtold":
[image]

My suspect is that the text marker jumps to the beginning of the ComboBox when the datasource is changed but the UI does not update immediately. You can see the marker beeing behind letter 1 once you typed a letter:
[image]

Is it possible to change / work around this behavior?

Best regards,

Julian Bechtold

EDIT:
The orientation is set left to right
[image]

Comment: Orientation is set `RightToLeft`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft?view=netframework-4.8 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.righttoleft?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: orientation is in fact set left to right

Comment: Then try: `user_dropdown.SelectionStart = user_dropdown.Text.Length` to set the cursor to the end after you update the `Text` property.

Comment: You just need: `if (user_dropdown.Text.Length == 0) return;
(user_dropdown.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = $"{user_dropdown.DisplayMember} LIKE '%{user_dropdown.Text}%'";`. You can remove all the rest. Since you don't have the AutoComplete feature do it for you, you could set `.DroppedDown = true`, to show the DropDown list while filtering. You can also mix the AutoComplete with your own filtering (that's a longer story, though).